# Any app/tool to keep some text highlighted in any app when the app loses focus?

Tags: windows, windows-8, multi-monitor

I have two monitors and one monitor could be showing text in an app like a text editor, pdf reader, help file, web page etc.. Then I need to change focus to the app on the second monitor. Even if I have highlighted some text to remember my last position in the document, the highlight is lost when I switch focus to the app.

I am looking for a system app or tool which allows me to highlight (or paint over) any text in any app and it stays fixed even if the underlying app loses focus. I am using Windows 8.1.

Any recommendations?

Comment: If the selection remains when you switch back then you are not loosing selection and just need to change the colour settings - look for colour of selected text in non-focus windows.  (Can't be more specific Windows 8 finally persuaded me to switch to Linux full time).